# Solving $\dot{v}(t) + \mu \text{ sgn}\{v(t)\} = f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to integrate the first order ODE
$$\dot{v}(t) + \mu \text{ sgn}\{v(t)\} = f(t)$$
to obtain $v(t)$.
The signum function in this equation gives the sign of $v$: $\text{ sgn}\{v\} = v/|v|.$ A perhaps useful fact is that $\frac{d}{dv}|v| = \text{sgn}(v).$

Is it possible to transform away the signum function somehow to obtain an equation which can be integrated?

Answer (score 1):

The common way of approximate integration of such systems is to replace the sign function with the arctangent:
$$\tag{1}
\dot{v}(t) =- \mu\cdot\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(M v(t)) + f(t)
$$
Here M is a constant that is chosen large enough.

System (1), unlike the original one, has a continuous right-hand side, thus, the solution to any initial value problem is unique and the system can be integrated in the usual way.

The choice of the arctangent function is not critical. You can also use a hyperbolic tangent, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious that this equation had solutions at all. The Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem does not apply here I think.

A simple variant of your equation could be $v\dot(t) + \mathrm{sign}(v(t))=0$.

If your function starts with a positive value, it will decay to zero in finite time, and then hit a singular point.

Edit: you can solve this formally in various intervals. If for $t=0$, $v>0$, then solve after replacing $\mathrm{sign}(v)$ with 1. You will get a solution which is valid until a sign change, then update the value of $\mathrm{sign}(v)$ and repeat.

Comment: Makes sense, but from a pragmatic viewpoint it'd be a bit surprising if it didn't, since from a physical point of view this equation describes the velocity of a particle driven with force $f(t)$ and resisted with coulomb friction

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be solved numerically. You need an if statement in your numerical integration. "If $v$ is positive the force acts this way, elseif the speed is 0, the force is zero, else the force acts the other way."

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to whether you can solve

$$\dot{v}(t) \pm \mu = f(t).$$

If you can, just solve that, then find the point at which $v(t)=0$. At that point, $\pm \mu$ turns into $\mp \mu$, so solve this new equation. Again, check for the earliest point that $v(t)$ would flip signs.